# Using monad for cumulative sum on list of pairs (haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I have a list of pairs structure `[("oct",1),("nov",1),("dec",1)]`

I want to calculate sum within pairs: `[("oct",1),("nov",2),("dec",3)]`. I think this is a good case for monadic implementation, but can't figure out how to preserve containers.

I tried to make function on lists (I already know about `scanl1`, just showing effort here :)

```
csm (x:[]) = [x]
csm (x:y:xs) = x : csm ((x + y) : xs)
```

And then try something like:

```
sumOnPairs l = do
  pair <- l
  return (csm (snd pair))
```

My solution is not working, please point me in the right direction

Comment: Monads can be used to model sequential processing, but that doesn't mean *every* monad models sequential processing. The list monad, for example, models nondetermism (do the same thing to every element of the list, then collect the results into a single new list). It doesn't really provide a natural (if any) way to make decisions, e.g, on how to process the second element of a list given the result of the processing of the first element.

Comment: I thought it is possible to "deconstruct" monads (List at first stage and then tuple), perform computations with values and then somehow "magically" return to initial form. Like there are ways to move through monadic contexts and juggle values :) Maybe I wanted too much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list monad models nondetermism: do the same thing to each element of the list, then collect the results in a new list.

For the type of sequential traversal you want (do something to an element, then use the result to do something to the next element, etc), you can use the `State` monad  to do something like

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Data.Bifunctor

type Pair = (String, Int)

foo :: Pair -> State Pair Pair
foo (month, y) = do
   -- bimap f g (x,y) == (f x, g y)
   -- The new month replaces the old month,
   -- and y is added to the sum.
   modify (bimap (const month) (+y))
   -- Return a snapshot of the state
   get
   

sumOnPairs :: [Pair] -> [Pair]
sumOnPairs = flip evalState ("", 0) . traverse foo
```

At each step, the new state is the current month and the sum
of the old state's number and the current number. `traverse` accumulates
those states in a list while traversing the original list.

```
> sumOnPairs [("oct",1),("nov",1),("dec",1)]
[("oct",1),("nov",2),("dec",3)]
```

---

You can also keep only the sum in the state, rather than a month that just gets replaced *and* the sum.

```
foo' :: Pair -> State Int Pair
foo' x@(_, count) = do
   modify (+ count)
   fmap (<$ x) get

sumOnPairs' :: [Pair] -> [Pair]
sumOnPairs' = flip evalState 0 . traverse bar
```

In this case, only the current sum is kept in the state; the new pair is generated by using the `<$` operator, which the `Functor` instance of `(,) String` to replace the number in the current pair with the sum in the state

```
> 6 <$ ("foo", 3)
("foo", 6)
```

I think using `Data.Functor.($>)` (the flipped version of `<$`) might be more readable, if you choose this route.

```
foo' x@(_, count) = do
   modify (+ count)
   fmap (x $>) get
```

Visually, it's more similar to what you could write if you didn't need to map over `get`: `x $> y == (fst x, y)`.

Comment: Why a `State Pair Pair` instead of a `State Int Pair`? `foo x@(_, count) = do { modify (+ count); fmap (<$ x) get }`

Comment: I barely remember that `<$` exists, let alone when and how to use it :)

Comment: Also tried to apply functor here. Thank you, need some time to study your answer and wrap my head around it

Comment: `traverse` makes use of the `Applicative` instance of `State`, while `foo'` uses two different functors: `fmap` uses the `State` instance and `(<$)` the `(,) [Char]` instance. At the lowest level, it's simple function composition, not a monad, that forces the elements of the input list to be treated in a particular order.